# Merge multiple Word files into one

Tags: javascript, ms-word, salesforce, glob

I want to merge multiple files into one file (MS Word) before the download. How can I achieve this?

The following code creates multiple word files and then downloads them.

```js
for (var k = 0; k < helper.reportGlob.length; k++) {
  var blob = new Blob([helper.reportGlob[k]], {
    type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'
  });
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  var a = document.createElement("a");

  a.href = url;
  a.download = 'output.docx';
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.style = 'display: none';
  a.click();
  a.remove();
}
```

Comment: There are libraries doing that, for example docx-merger [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/docx-merger)

Comment: @Mike thanks for your response. i did try to use that but unfortunetly the file gets corrupted because the template contains some html code, that's why i use docx-templater and it is not compatible with docxmerger